# How to detect user already logged out from Google at my GAE website

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I don't have problem to have Google authentication login module added to my GAE website.

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint> 
  <web-resource-collection> 
    <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </web-resource-collection> 
  <auth-constraint> 
    <role-name>*</role-name> 
  </auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
```

But then when I sign out from Google, my web client still holds the cookie name with "SACSID" which thinks my Google account still valid. How to overcome such issue???

Answer (score 0):

Provide a sign out link in your app. A user signing out of their Google account only affects first-party services; your users have to sign out separately from your app.

Comment: zzz, I need an API to check google.com cookies so that my app can log out together =.='