# How to synchronize Google sign out to GAE logout as well

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect user already logged out from Google at my GAE website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930186/how-to-detect-user-already-logged-out-from-google-at-my-gae-website)

How do to this: If I want to to log out from my GAE application once I click "Sign out" from Google website. I want my GAE identity synchronize with Google website.

Comment: I don't actually see a solution to this, perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @lannyboy, this is identical to the question you asked yesterday...